# How to friend a test user that does not have app installed?

Tags: php, facebook

Using the Facebook developers site editing the roles of a test user, I am able to make friends using two test users, one with the app installed and one without.

I have created two Facebook test users using the graph API.  If both users have the app installed I can make friend connections between them using the graph API and the user's access tokens.  If I create one test user with the app installed and one without the app installed the user without the app installed does not have a user access token.  How can I friend these two users programmatically without them both having an accesses token?

Answer (score 0):

For the API to work, you need an access token for each test user.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

> **Making friend connections**
>
> You can use the API to make friends connections for a test user with
>   other test users of that app. We provide an API for creating a friend
>   request as well as for accepting a friend request. This enables
>   developers to create several friend connections between test users via
>   the API itself, without having to log-in as the test user to accept
>   requests.
>
> **API**
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_USER_1_ID/friends/TEST_USER_2_ID?
>   method=post   &access_token=TEST_USER_1_ACCESS_TOKEN
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_USER_2_ID/friends/TEST_USER_1_ID?
>   method=post   &access_token=TEST_USER_2_ACCESS_TOKEN
>
> ```
> The first call should be made with access token of TEST_USER_1_ID. This will creates a friend request from TEST_USER_1_ID to
> ```
>
> TEST_USER_2_ID.
>       The second call should be made with access token for TEST_USER_2_ID and will confirm the request.
>
> Response: true on success, false otherwise